# Efficient way in MATLAB to apply the same left and right matrix multiplication to a large set of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a lot of 2-by-2 matrices S1, S2, ..., SN, and on each of those matrices, I want to perform a left and right matrix multiplication as in R*S*R^T, where R is also a 2-by-2 matrix. Obviously I could just write this with a for loop, but I anticipate it being very slow for large N in MATLAB. Is there a simple and efficient way to accomplish this without using a for loop? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your biggest problem is not the loops. For matrices so small calling MATLABs `A*B` introduces a lot of overhead. The best thing you can do is to store  all the matrices in a large `4 x n_matrices` matrix and spell out the matrix multiplications manually:

```
A = rand(4, 1000);
B = rand(4, 1000);

tic;
C = zeros(size(A));
C(1,:) = A(1,:).*B(1,:) + A(3,:).*B(2,:);
C(2,:) = A(2,:).*B(1,:) + A(4,:).*B(2,:);
C(3,:) = A(1,:).*B(3,:) + A(3,:).*B(4,:);
C(4,:) = A(2,:).*B(3,:) + A(4,:).*B(4,:);
toc

Elapsed time is 0.020950 seconds.
```

As you see, this takes little time (this is a 6-years old desktop PC). For small matrices like this it is practical and I can not imagine anything else written in MATLAB that could beat this performance-wise. Well, for very large number of `2x2` matrices you could introduce blocking (i.e., handle only a number of matrices at a time) to enhance cache reuse.

Comment: I was about to write out the multiplications as well. Thanks for saving me the work :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You pointed out an important issue that I was not really aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the cycle here is not that bad and not that slow, consider this

```
N = 1000000
S = cell(1,N);
Out = S;
A = rand(2);
B = rand(2);

for i = 1 : N     
    S{i} = rand(2);
end

tic
for i = 1 : N
    Out{i} = A * S{i} * B;    
end
toc

tic
  f = @(i) A*i*B;
  Out = cellfun(f,S,'UniformOutput' , false);  
toc


  N =

 1000000

   Elapsed time is 2.609569 seconds.
   Elapsed time is 9.871200 seconds.
```

You may think of performing a `cat` of your 2x2 matrices and then performing just 2 multiplications (transposing correctly on the way). But you will loose time in `cat`ting.